# Programmatically detect Memory Leaks on other apps?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am trying to make an app that will monitor if other apps are having a memory leak and alerts the user but i cant get the right way to do it, or if it is possible anyhow.

What can be done is using

```
adb shell dumpsys procstats
```

Which even google mentions to be used for finding memory leaks, but i cannot get how it can be used to detect them.

Another solution i thought of was trying to use

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo
```

and experimenting with different scenarios, but looks like a solution i though of.
I hope someone with more experience can give hints in this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this library: https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: I have stumbled on LeakCanary as well, but the way i understood it, it is an application itself, and i have the task to make mine. I can reuse stuff, but this looks really huge and complicated. Not sure where to begin and what parts to reuse if i go that way to be honest :)

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I can't help more here.. hopefully someone with more experience in this topic will answer :)

Comment: looks like rather no one has a solution around sadly :)